# Search and tag page numbers between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
df = ['sentence1', 'sentence2', 'sentence3', 'sentence4']
df_pages = {['para1', 'pgno'], ['para2', 'pgno']
```

df - One column dataframe
df_pages - two columns (paragraph and pagenumber).
Excuse the way i have mentioned df and df_pages.

I am trying to search df in df_pages, and if the sentences are present in any of the two paras - i would like to extract the page number associated. Till now i have tried the following:

```
for i in df['column']:
for j in df_pages['column']:
    if i in j:
        print(df_pages['PageNumber'])
```

However, it is printing entire column multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are printing the entire column with `df_pages['PageNumber']`. Try adding the row index to the expression.

```
for i in df['column']:
for idx, j in enumerate(df_pages['column']):
    if i in j:
        print(df_pages.loc[idx, 'PageNumber'])
```

Assuming that your index is numeric and starts from zero, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

`df_pages['PageNumber']` prints the entire column. You have to specify the row you want to print.



**Solution 1:** You can add a row index to achieve this. `count` represents the row index.

```
for i in df['column']:
    for count,j in enumerate(df_pages['column']):
        if i in j:
            print(df_pages['PageNumber'][count])
```

**Solution 2:** You can also use `.loc` like @czr suggested:

```
for i in df['column']:
    for count, j in enumerate(df_pages['column']):
        if i in j:
            print(df_pages.loc[count, 'PageNumber'])
```

This is the data I used to recreate your example.
Both solutions work with this data and print `234` in this case.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'column':['sentence1', 'sentence2', 'sentence3', 'sentence4']})
df_pages = pd.DataFrame({'column':['para1 sentence1', 'para2'], 'PageNumber':['234', '567']})
#>> 234
```